# Quote function name in Elixir

Tags: function, macros, elixir, quote

I'm learning Elixir now and I'm really confused with `quote` and `unquote`.
Here is how we create a function with a dynamic name using a `macro`:

```
defmacro create_fun(n) do
  quote do: def unquote(:"times_#{n}")(a), do: a * 4
end
```

It creates function `times_6`, for example, if I pass `6` as a macro parameter.

**Now what I don't understand:** Here we unquote the atom `:"times_#{n}"`. Elixir docs say that when you quote an atom it returns an atom. So when I unquote an atom, I should get this atom back too. And this is true:

```
iex(15)> Macro.to_string quote do: unquote(:"times_6")
":times_6"
```

But using `()` right after the quote gives this:

```
iex(14)> Macro.to_string quote do: unquote(:"times_6")()
"times_6()"
```

An atom with parentheses suddenly becomes not an atom. And if I substitute `unquote(:"times_6")` with `:"times_6"` it doesn't work:

```
iex(4)> Macro.to_string quote do: :"times_6"()
** (SyntaxError) iex:4: syntax error before: '('
```

Please, what is going on, I don't get it

Comment: Shouldn't it be `do: a * unquote(n)` instead of `a * 4` ?

Comment: Yes. It should. But this is not the point. This macro works fine. I just try to understand why there is difference with parentheses. Because at first I didn't know that quoting/unquoting atom with parentheses suddenly returns you not an atom.

Comment: The issue here isn't with the macro, it's with `:"times_6"()`. That itself is an invalid statement

Comment: Yes. But why is `unquote(:"times_6")()` correct? `unquote(:"times_6")` should return you `:"times_6"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### That's how `quote` & `unquote` are implemented in Elixir

From the [Elixir Metaprogramming Guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html#unquoting):

> The building block of an Elixir program is a tuple with three
>   elements. For example, the function call `sum(1, 2, 3)` is represented
>   internally as:
>
> ```
> iex> quote do: sum(1, 2, 3)
> {:sum, [], [1, 2, 3]}
> ```
>
> The first element is the function name, the second is a keyword list
>   containing metadata and the third is the arguments list.

---

Module and Method names are internally represented as `atoms` in elixir. Looking directly at the underlying elixir data generated when calling `unquote(:"hello")` and `unquote(:"hello")()` might help clear this up:

```
iex(27)> quote do: unquote(:"hello")   
:hello

iex(28)> quote do: unquote(:"hello")() 
{:hello, [], []}
```

The first one simply returns an atom while the second one returns an **Elixir Data Structure** (a tuple composed of 3 elements) which represents a function call to the `hello` method with 0 arguments. The `unquote(:"hello")()` is transformed into `hello()` which is then used as a method.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep in mind that presence of parentheses changes quote/unquote behavior for atoms. And sorry my inattention

Comment: `unquote(:"hello")()` is not “transformed” any further, it’s already an AST, representing a function. It’s vice versa: `hello()` in source code _is transformed_ to `{:hello, [], []}` AST by compiler :)

Comment: Yes, I know that, but was trying to phrase it in a way that would be easier to understand. Guess I did the opposite.